# Bitnami WAMP and mysqli

Tags: php, wamp

I have just started using WAMP.  Something strange is happening with the use of mysqli as opposed to mysql statements.  When connecting a php program using mysqli I get
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

If I use a mysql_connect everything works fine so it can't be a credentials issue with the database (everyone keeps saying that) - and mysqli and mysql work fine with windows and IIS using the same login info so once again that is not the issue.  I am using the latest build of WAMP and can't find a thing about this issue.  Anybody else encounter this?
Any help is appreciated -

Comment: First thought is there's an issue with your `mysqli_connect(...)` function. Are you using `$conn = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "database") or die("mysqli_error($conn);` Note that `"database"` isn't required here, but should none-the-less be specified.

Comment: Here is my connection string

DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'root'); DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', '######'); DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'maxibillions');

// Make the connection: $dbc = mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

Comment: `maxibillions` Heh. Well, everything looks fine there, only other thing I can think of is you don't have permissions set correctly on that database. By defauly, `mysql_connect(...)` doesn't specify the database to connect to (I think), so it wouldn't throw that error. Do queries work when using `mysql_query()`?

Comment: Yeah - everything works fine when mysql is used - can't get past the connect stage when using mysqli and the permissions are set wide open in phpmyAdmin - maxibillions = schrute bucks :)